# How to generate an image of clothing based on the image of this clothing on some model (person) while preserving details

Tags: pytorch, image-generation, diffusion-models

I have a task to generate an image of clothing based on the image of this clothing on some model (person). I tried different variations of diffusion models to reach the goal, but all of them had failed. The main problem is preserving the details of clothing (difficult patterns, prints etc.) when passing the conditional image to some encoder (e.g. clip, dinov2 etc.).

Is there any method to reach the goal of detail preservation with diffusion or are there any other models that can help me?

Comment: Do you have training data (example source and target images)? If so, how much? If not, how are you measuring performance of your model?

Comment: I have training data (pairs of source image -- target image) in quantity of 20k (augmented to 100k via variating permutation of RGB and flipping)